# $(\omega +3)\cdot\omega=\omega\cdot\omega$

Tags: set-theory, book-recommendation, ordinals

Show that $(\omega +3)\cdot\omega=\omega\cdot\omega$.

Is this just $(\omega +3)\cdot\omega=(\omega +\omega)\cdot\omega=\omega\cdot\omega$?

Also, could someone suggest a good book for set theory?

Comment: What is $\omega$ here?

Comment: @gt6989b In view of the (ordinals) tag, I guess $\omega$ is the lieast infinite ordinal.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Does the duplicate policy of math.se allow us to overlook the fact that $2\ne3$?

Comment: @bof Wait, $2\not=3$? Crud, there goes that paper. :P I think in this context it's close enough to be a duplicate.

Comment: @bof both are examples of an $n$, and the reasoning is the same ;-)

Comment: Book recommendations: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491464/212120

Comment: @Noah: I take a narrow view of what constitutes a duplicate: I’m not willing to call that one a duplicate unless the OP agrees that it answers the question.

Comment: One of the best serious set theory texts at the advanced undergraduate/beginning graduate level is Hrbacek & Jech, [*Introduction to Set Theory, Third Edition, Revised and Expanded*](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/0824779150).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Generally, I agree with that policy, but it sure seems in this instance that $3$ can very easily be viewed as a special case of $2$.

Comment: What about Enderton? Is that any good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the following lines follow immediately from the definition of ordinal multiplication $\alpha \cdot \lambda$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$. On the one hand, we have

$
\begin{align*}
  (\omega + 3) \cdot \omega
  =& \sup \{ (\omega + 3) \cdot n \mid n < \omega \} \\
  \ge& \sup \{ \omega \cdot n \mid n < \omega \} \\
  =& \omega \cdot \omega.
\end{align*}
$

On the other hand

$
\begin{align*}
  (\omega + 3) \cdot \omega
  =& \sup \{ (\omega + 3) \cdot n \mid n < \omega \} \\
  \le& \sup \{ (\omega + \omega) \cdot n \mid n < \omega \} \\
  =& \sup \{ \omega \cdot (n+1) \mid n < \omega \} \\
  =& \omega \cdot \omega.
\end{align*}
$

Hence $(\omega + 3) \cdot \omega = \omega \cdot \omega$.

Comment: I think you have to use normality (or continuity) of the ordinal product to justify last displayed step (i.e., $\sup \{ \omega \cdot (n+1) \mid n < \omega \}
  = \omega \cdot \omega$.)

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf $\{\omega \cdot (n+1) \mid n < \omega \} = \{\omega \cdot n \mid 0 < n < \omega \} \subseteq \{ \omega \cdot n \mid n < \omega \}$. Hence $\sup \{ \omega \cdot (n+1) \mid n < \omega \} \le \omega \cdot \omega$ and monotonicity actually yields equality.

Comment: That's perfect; the point I wanted to make is that you need to use a bit more than the bare definition of product.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to get $\sup \{ (\omega + \omega) \cdot n \mid n < \omega \} = \sup \{ \omega \cdot (n+1) \mid n < \omega \}$?

Comment: @LeAnhDung Note that, for $0 < n < \omega$, $\omega \cdot (n+1) = \omega \cdot n + \omega \le \omega \cdot n + \omega \cdot n = (\omega + \omega) \cdot n = (\omega \cdot 2) \cdot n = \omega \cdot (2n)$.

Comment: Please confirm my understanding! We have $(\omega + \omega) \cdot n=(\omega \cdot 2) \cdot n=\omega \cdot (2n)$. Thus our job is to prove $\sup \{ \omega \cdot (n+1) \mid n < \omega \} = \sup \{ \omega \cdot (2n) \mid n < \omega \}$. We have $\{ \omega \cdot (2n) \mid 0<n < \omega \} \subseteq \{ \omega \cdot (n+1) \mid 0<n < \omega \}$ and $\forall 0<n < \omega,\exists 0<n' < \omega:\omega \cdot (n+1)<\omega \cdot (2n')$. The result is then followed.

Comment: @LeAnhDung Yep, that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated help ;)

Comment: @LeAnhDung You're most welcome!

Answer (score 5):

By using only that the ordinal product is associative, non-decreasing in each variable, and the fact that $2\cdot\omega=\omega$, you can make your argument formal.

Since $\cdot$ is monotonic,
$$
(\omega +3)\cdot\omega\geq\omega\cdot\omega.
$$
By the same reason,
$$
(\omega +3)\cdot\omega\leq(\omega +\omega)\cdot\omega=(\omega\cdot 2)\cdot\omega= \omega\cdot(2\cdot\omega),
$$
where the last equality follows by associativity. Finally, since $2\cdot\omega=\omega$, we obtain
$$
(\omega +3)\cdot\omega\leq\omega\cdot(2\cdot\omega) = \omega\cdot\omega.
$$
Hence we have both inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}(\omega+3)+(\omega+3)+(\omega+3)\dots&=\omega+(3+\omega)+(3+\omega)+(3+\omega)+(3+\omega)\dots \\
&=\omega+\omega+\omega+\omega+\dots \\
&=\omega\cdot\omega
\end{align*}

Comment: I only used associativity.

Comment: And infinite sums...