# asking references to study logic

Tags: logic, reference-request

I have difficulty in understanding the axiomatic approach of set theory and i decided to study logic.After seeing some lectures on set theory my doubt grown up like a beast.

So please  suggest me some good books in logic and in set theory which will help me understand what the concepts are.ALSO SUGGEST ME SOME GOOD VIDEO LECTURES IF AVAILABLE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Peter Smith's [Teach Yourself Logic](http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/) has some annotated recommendations.

Comment: Understanding ZFC set theory does require prior understanding of logic. Analyzing logic itself would require working in some meta-system, which many logicians choose to be ZFC, but most basic theorems are provable in very much weaker meta-systems, where it is enough if you know how to reason about programs (or Turing-machines).

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1497280/212120) there are some book recommendations for learning Set Theory. The other answers to that question are also very useful.

Nevertheless, I'm posting this as an answer because I recently found some video lectures by Harvey Friedman, that intend to give the "big picture" for undergraduates. These were given during 5 days at the beginning of 2011, with the following topics:

- [Logical Connectives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOMGZOMGSec),
- [Logical Quantifiers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaAlbn6mDeQ),
- [Turing Machines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2wwBJ1yk4A),
- [Goedel’s Blessing and Goedel’s Curse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esH8SkSIHdI), and
- [Foundations of Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mogMr45UTj4).

I didn't go through all of them yet, but the first two have a nice, incremental approach that might be useful.