# Is there a good free online resource for learning axiomatic set theory?

Tags: set-theory, book-recommendation, axioms

Is there a good (free) online resource for learning axiomatic set theory? I am no mathematician, but I have basic familiarity with calculus, combinatorics, and basic computability theory. Wikipedia, in typical encyclopaedia fashion, is a bit too dense, and lacks exercises.

Comment: what is wrong with reading a good old fashioned book ?

Comment: You can start with Stephen Simpson, [Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/fom.pdf) (2009).

Comment: "An old-fashioned book" is generally more difficult to access.

Comment: Almost all math books can be found online these days.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you! Although it seems most axiomatic set theory starts a bit late in the book, and runs for only a few dozen pages before the book is over :) But it definitely seems a good starting point. Anything AFTER that?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus then great, a free online math book is a free online resource and qualifies as an answer. But what's wrong with being open about *other* resources too?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, its just that I got the impression from your question that you wanted a website. For those people serious about learning set theory the books  Kunnen, Set theory, and Jech, Set Theory remain the two basic resources. I would recommend starting with Kunnen. Of course there are other books but eventually one ends up looking at those two.

Comment: @ReneSchipperius I  ... *found* a copy of the Kunen (Kunen, right? Not KunNen) online :) It's from 1980. Isn't it a bit old?
But delving into it it seems to have far more substance than any other suggestion I received so far. I would accept it as an answer!

Comment: I was once in the library and there were two students looking for a calculus text. One student found a book and his friend looked at the date and said "1989 that is a bit old isnt it ?"  and the student replied "Dude, calculus was invented in then 18 th century."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best book is "Axiomatic Set theory" by Patrick Suppes.

Also note this [PDF](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~randre/1aaset_theory_140613.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjGzK2H5NDRAhWIuo8KHbTLAYgQFgiLATAP&usg=AFQjCNHr4kSjn_iKSWuY11bSb2DdYIEqDQ&sig2=RqkZELKZcGkHLyd28YFXXw) is quite good (by Robert Andre). Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh thanks. It looks quite well done. I would upvote your answer, but it seems I have not enough reputation yet (11/15 needed).

Comment: I just gave you the rep. you need.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus thanks :)

Comment: @blackbadger Also Kunen's book on set theory is very good ( just read the comments!). Happy reading!

Answer (score 0):

There is a preliminary version of the introductory text on Set Theory by W. Weiss in [his website](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.html). It is a very nice material.

Once you cope with the basic stuff and *after* you've seen some material on Martin's Axiom, you could check out the notes of [Forcing](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/223s.1.11s/) by Itay Neeman. There he refers to some notes by J. Palumbo, but I think those are not available online any more. There were pretty useful for me.

---

Concerning book suggestions, I completely agree with @ReneSchipperus. Now, there is a 2011 Set Theory by Kunen. It's a slightly different book on exactly the same subject; perhaps more streamlined. Both the old and new are excellent choices, along with Jech's 3rd edition. For more elementary suggestions, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1497280/212120).